How to define measures automatically via PowerBi custom connector
We are planning to build a PowerBI custom connector for our product. The backend would be mostly responding with csv / json tabular data, however this data may require some special interpretation at PowerBI level. Basically we have - and ~ (no rollup) rollup operators which don't work in powerbi aggregation.
We have found the way to define a custom measure using ISINSCOPE function to perform this custom aggregation in matrix and other visualization (it's a standard technique used by many to determine the level of record and multiply the value with -1 / 1 while summing up).
Now the question is that we want to automatically define the necessary measures by our custom connector when the model is loaded in PowerBI. We dont want user to do this every time they load the model.
Is there any way in PowerQuery SDK to achieve this ? I hit upon C# scripts to define the measures but I am still exploring, and am really not clear how C# script would go inside custom connector.
Any help / direction is appreciated.
